# Sorting array with uncertain property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to write a function for sorting array of objects with dynamic property for sorting. But it doesn't work. When i write `item1.calories` it's all right. But when i use `item1.prop` (prop === calories) it doesn't work. I tried to `console.log(prop === "calories")` and result was true. Why cant i sort my array like this? Thanks.

```
var products = [
    { name: "Item1", calories: 170 },
    { name: "Item2", calories: 160 }
];

function sortFunc(item1, item2)
{
    var selectedOption = document.getElementById("selectField");
    var prop = selectedOption.options[selectedOption.selectedIndex].value; //prop == calories

    console.log(prop == "calories"); //true

    if(item1.prop > item2.prop)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(item1.prop === item2.prop)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

function execSorting()
{
    products.sort(sortFunc);
    //here is function for displaying my array. It is not sorted.
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use _bracket notation_, i.e. `obj[key]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for "prop" not a variable prop in the object.

You need to use bracket notation, NOT dot notation.

```
...
if(item1[prop] > item2[prop])
{
    return 1;
}
else if(item1[prop] === item2[prop])
...
```

Comment: I thought that dot notation is equal to bracket notation. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

`prop` is not a property of the product. It's a single variable that exists within the function. If there is only 1 value at the 1 selected index then prop only has 1 value and can be called just as you would any other standard variable.